# LDAP query to extract members from AD server

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm in LDAP and Active Directory. I'm connecting to AD like this:

- Host: `ad.myhostname.com`
- Base DN: `CN=GGM-FOX-MANAGER,OU=ClaimRoles,OU=Groups,OU=ENT,DC=ad,DC=myhostname,dc=com`

I want to extract all users from the `GGM-FOX-MANAGER` group

When I am trying to use this query, I'm getting no users:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=CN=GGM-FOX-MANAGER,OU=ClaimRoles,OU=Groups,OU=ENT,DC=ad,DC=myhostname,dc=com))
```

So I opened the UI page where I can see the data structure in AD

1. Searched for group `GGM-FOX-MANAGER`
2. Page opened of `GGM-FOX-MANAGER`
3. Expanded `GGM-FOX-MANAGER`, saw below 3 new categories

   ```
    Members
    Member Of
    General Properties
   ```
4. When I click on `Members`, I can see my all users list in `three` columns

   ```
    Name Type Description
   ```

   where `Type` for all users is `User`

Where User's DN name is

```
CN=12300,OU=Employees,OU=Users;DC=BR,DC=AD,DC=myhostname,DC=com
```

Above dn is including `DC=BR` additionally - is that a problem?

And more over, while opened `Members` tab, I can see this path as well, under which my users are there

```
ActiveDirectory/ad.myhostname.com/ENT/Groups/ClaimRoles
```

May I know please, what query I should use to extract all members?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is likely that you set your Base DN to DN of the group. You will need to set your Base DN to distinguishedName that is common both for group you're using **and** location of users you're searching for.

In this case it should be enough to set **Base DN** to value **DC=ad,DC=myhostname,dc=com**